# Rounding integers to one significant digit

Tags: java, integer, rounding

I want to round down an int in Java, what i mean is, if I have an int 45678, i want to convert that int into 40000

this is how im calling it

```
 int den = placeValue(startCode,length);
```

and this is the code

```
    static int placeValue(int N, int num)
    {
        int total = 1, value = 0, rem = 0;
        while (true) {
            rem = N % 10;
            N = N / 10;

            if (rem == num) {
                value = total * rem;
                break;
            }

            total = total * 10;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

so if i have 89765, i would want 80000,
but instead it return the place value of whatever length is.
So,
for 89765, the length would be 5, so the return value is 5 i.e. the value in the ones place.

but if the number was 85760
then it would return 5000.
I hope that makes sense.
Any suggestions would be much appreicated.

Comment: This is a very strange algorithm. It drops the low order digit until it happens to find the one equal to parameter `num`, then replaces all the dropped ones with zeros and returns. In fact if it never finds the one it's looking for, it will loop infinitely.  I.e. try `num` of 4 on input `123567`.  The first thing you'll need to do is ask the question you really want answered.  Give complete examples of _all_ inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: It is unclear what your parameters are supposed to represent.

Comment: What does it mean `startCode`?

Comment: Naming a parameter that is a number `num` Tells us nothing about what it means. Please rename the parameter with a sensible, meaningful name and/or tell is what it is supposed to be for.

Comment: The easy way to do this is something like `value -= value % (int)Math.pow(10, Math.log10(value))`, but it won't work for negative numbers. E&OE

Comment: I apologize I should have been more clear on what I wanted. I am indeed new to stack overflow, I was trying to use this for a coding challenge we were assigned in my data structures class. To put it simply the challenge is a to write a program to help a burglar crack codes and you have to iterate through each number on each dial until you reach the target code. What I thought would be a good idea was to get the place value of if the first digit in a number and that would be the number on the dial which I would start moving up or down, so like code:4578 place value of 4:1000 4578/1000=4 start:4

Answer (score -1):

In my opinions, if I can avoid 'calculating' I will compute the answer from other concept since I am not confidence on my math (haha).

Here is my answer. (only work in positive numbers)
I think the length of the inputted number is not necessary.

```
static int placeValue2(int N) {
    String tar = N+"";
    String rtn = tar.substring(0,1);    // take first digital
    for (int i=0;i<tar.length()-1;i++)  // pad following digitals
        rtn+="0";
        
    return Integer.parseInt(rtn);
}
```

Comment: Don't use concatenation to convert an int to a String. Don't concatenate strings in a loop.  Use a StringBuilder.

Comment: errrr... I remember Java had optimized string concatenation years ago.

Comment: If you are referring to the use of invoke dynamic for string concatenation (JEP 280), it was introduced in Java 9, but it doesn't negate the uselessness of concatenating when you don't need to. Concatenation in a loop, like above, still generates a lot of garbage. The ""+N pattern is still a "never do this" as of Java 18.

Comment: Worth a look regarding string concatenation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w56RUzBLaRE&t=760s

Comment: i mean, maybe i use string concatenation, but actually, it turn to StringBuilder by compiler automatically. if we don't have big performance issue, why not make life easier. https://medium.com/javarevisited/java-compiler-optimization-for-string-concatenation-7f5237e5e6ed

Comment: But you don't want what the compiler does for you: ```String tar = new StringBuilder().append(Integer.toString(N)).append("").toString();``` instead of ```String tar = Integer.toString(N);```   The "easy" way isn't much easier and the result is worse.  Obviously the real world effect depends on how the code is used. It is just a bad habit.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate you asked the question here.
Here is my solution. I don't know why you are taking two parameters, but I tried it from one param.

```
class PlaceValue{
 int placeValue(int num){
    int length = 0; int temp2=1;
    boolean result=false;
    long temp1=1;
    if (num<0){
        result=true;
        num=num*(-1);
    }
    if (num==0){
        System.out.println("Value 0 not allowed");
        return 0;
    }
    while (temp1 <= num){ //This loop checks for the length, multiplying temp1 with 10 
                        //untill its <= number. length++ counts the length.
        length++;
        temp1*=10;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<length; i++){//this loop multiplies temp2 with 10 length number times.
                        // like if length 2 then 100. if 5 then 10000
        temp2=temp2*10;
    }
    temp2=(num/temp2)*temp2;
    /* Let's say number is 2345. This would divide it over 1000, giving us 2;
    in the same line multiplying it with the temp2 which is same 1000 resulting 2000.
    now 2345 became 2000;
    */
    if (result==true){
        temp2=temp2*(-1);
    }
    return temp2;
}
```

}

Here is the code above. You can try this. If you are dealing with the long numbers, go for long in function type as well as the variable being returned and in the main function. I hope you understand. otherwise, ask me.

Comment: You don't need two multiply-by-ten loops. You don't need `temp2` at all. It attains the same value as `temp1/10`. You don't need to compare booleans to `true`. The `result` variable is poorly named. Poor quality code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear @mohammadmobasher . Respectfully, the user seems to be a little new to programming so the code should be student-friendly and easy to understand. I placed boolean to help him understand the concept of boolean as well and use that to mark if the value was negative instead of making large if-else blocks and increasing code content. 
My main target was to make him understand how each step worked instead of only solving problems and writing a short complex code that he is not gonna understand.

Comment: All code should be easy to understand. This isn't. The whole thing can be solved in one line of code. You don't need all this.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this?

```
public static int roundDown(int number, int magnitude) {
    int mag = (int) Math.pow(10, magnitude);
    return (number / mag) * mag;
}
```

`roundDown(53278,4)` -> `50000`

`roundDown(46287,3)` -> `46000`

`roundDown(65478,2)` -> `65400`

`roundDown(43298,1)` -> `43290`

`roundDown(43278,0)` -> `43278`

So the equivalent that will only use the most significant digit is:

```
    public static int roundDown(int number) {
        int zeros = (int) Math.log10(number);
        int mag = (int) Math.pow(10, zeros);
        return (number / mag) * mag;
    }
```